# autocomplete bootstrap php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

```
                autocomplete bootstrap php mysql ajax
```

> autocomplete bootstrap php mysql from databse 
>   data not fetching from database not showing suggestion
>   **my code not showing any result please help to complete my code 
>    i have change many time my code**

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
     <head>
             <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typehead with Ajax PHP</title>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
         </head>
         <body>
```

Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typeahead with Ajax PHP
                
                 Search Country
                
              
               
                    
            // script
                   
               $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#country').typeahead({
                  source: function(query, result)
            {
       $.ajax({
       url:"autoselect_jquery5.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query},
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data)
     {
      result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
         }));
          }
           })
            }
               });

```
        });
         </script>






         // autoselect_jquery5.php


          <?php
            include 'database.php';

             if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
            // $search_query = $_POST['query'];
              $search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST["query"]);

          $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE '%".$search_query."%' LIMIT 12";
     // $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE  %' 
         $search_query ' LIMIT 12";
          $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $data = array();

         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
     {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
    $data[] = $row["address"];
        }
     echo json_encode($data);
      }
       }
       ?>
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting for autoselect_jquery5.php. Notice it looks weird? You have a syntax error, so start there.

Comment: Agree with @aynber. `$search_query ' LIMIT 12";` is the problem. You have a `'` and then a `"` which treats the remaining code as a non-functional string.

Comment: thanks please write right code

Comment: sir i paste my answer but not working . what is the other reason why not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your file.  I have commented this up fully to help others who come across this question.

```
<?php
//Assume this line is correct and that you have a database.php file containing your log in credientials
include 'database.php';

//If Statement says - run this next piece of code if $_POST['query'] is set to something 
if (isset($_POST['query']))
{

// $search_query = $_POST['query']; - Commented OUT
//This line attempts to sanatise the input from the posted data
$search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST["query"]);

//This line constructs the whole SQL statement ( BAd methodology here, but thats a different topic)
$query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE '%".$search_query."%' LIMIT 12";

//You've commented out the next line and its of no use
// $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE  %' 

//This line has a syntax error - but is also of no use - Should delete but should read  $search_query = ' LIMIT 12';
//$search_query ' LIMIT 12";

/// This line queries the database
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//This line declares $data will be an array
$data = array();

//If the DB returns some rows
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    // While there are results
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //add to the $data array
        $data[] = $row["address"];
    }
    //Output $data in JSON format to be interpreted as a response from your ajax call
    echo json_encode($data);
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: sir i have copied code to file but not working what other reason can effects my code sir please help

Comment: Please do not 'COPY' the code, I have marked it up to help you identify what the stages are within the process.  You need some tools to help identify what reponses/errors are being generated. The faults could be many such as incorrect DB credentials, bad filepaths, etc. Does the DB even exist?

Comment: You need to trace the following.  1. Is your ajax request actually firing? 2. Is the ajax request triggering the correct file? 3. Is the DB Credentials in database.php correct? 4. Is the $_POST data being received? 5. Is the SQL statement correct after being amalgamated with the $_POST data. 6. Is the SQL creating a response (and an accurate one) from the DB? 7. Is the JSON being formed? And finally, is the AJAX receiving the response.

Comment: sir  i check my console network ajax status 200 type xhr  it show result   but on front end showing no result  please can u tell why not showing

Comment: then you have now checked parts 1 and 2.  You now need to check the other points I mentioned.  Start by outputting something versy simple in your file such as  echo "hello world" and then start testing each part of the file.  Anything you output in that php file will come back as the ajax response.

Comment: Still not working doesn't tell me anything.  what have you tried?

Comment: it is working becuse i have html code in database file that is why not  working

Comment: Great news, I am very happy that you got there in the end.  Well done.